Can we use WebRTC to forward a port? If yes then how?
For few days now I am exploring ways to establish peer to peer connection over the internet. I wish to share a port from a computer to another (like VsCode does). Python is my preferred language though I understand usage of low-level language may be necessary.
Since I know WebRTC can establish peer to peer connection between peers and it can use used for transferring of audio, video and data.  I believe it can fulfil my task.
How can this be achieved? I am open to all possible ways but have one restriction. The peers are behind NAT and port forwarding cant be done. Thus hole punching is the only way I suppose.
Also, it would be great if a Symmetric NAT peer could connect to another Non-Symmetric NAT peer using this method
